# For jqGrid: calling $(document).on('click'..) in keypress event doesnt work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, onclick, keypress

Im trying to allow up/down keys in jqGrid rows and trigger a document click function but my calling methods doesnt work correctly. This code :

```
$("#table_list_1").on("keyup", "tr", function(e)
        {
        //    $("#table_list_1").unbindKeys(e);
        //$("#table_list_1").bindKeys(e);
            if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40)  //up/down arrow override
            {
                var gridArr = $('#table_list_1').getDataIDs();
                var selrow = $('#table_list_1').getGridParam("selrow");
                var curr_index = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < gridArr.length; i++)
                {
                    if(gridArr[i]==selrow)
                        curr_index = i;
                }

                if(e.keyCode == 38) //up
                {
                    if((curr_index-1)>=0)
                        $('#table_list_1').resetSelection().setSelection(gridArr[curr_index-1],true);
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 40) //down
                {
                    if((curr_index+1)<gridArr.length)
                        $('#table_list_1').resetSelection().setSelection(gridArr[curr_index+1],true);
                }

               // $(document).on('click', '#table_list_1 tr');
                //$('#table_list_1 tr').click();


//$('#table_list_1tr').jqGrid('setSelection',curr_index+1,true)
                //var c = jQuery.Event("click");
                //$(document).trigger(c);
                $('#table_list_1 tr').trigger('click'); //any of these does not working right.
            }

        });
```

like this, ive tried various calling method. This is document on click:

```
 try {
        $(document).on('click', '#table_list_1 tr', function (e) {
            alert();
            var id = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
            var lastname = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            var firstname = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
            document.getElementById("urunad").value = firstname;

            //   alert(id);  code goes on...
```

i couldnt worked it correct. Do you have any ideas where do i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After creating your jqgrid use [bindKeys](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) as in the following code

```
 $("#table_list_1").jqGrid('bindKeys');
```